# mongoose virtual attribute not populating in some cases where populate() is used

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to populate the `job.creator` and use the virtual attribute from the `User` object (`user.profile`) to give only public information for the job creator.

```
/**
 * User Schema
 */
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    favorites: {
        jobs: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Job', index: true }]
    }
});

// Public profile information
UserSchema
.virtual('profile')
.get(function () {
    return {
        favorites: this.favorites,
        profileImageUrls: this.profileImageUrls //also not being populated
    };
});


UserSchema
.virtual('profileImageUrls')
.get(function(){
    var  defaultUrl = cfg.home + '/images/cache/default-profile-img.png'
        , smallUrl = cfg.home + '/images/cache/default-profile-img-small.png';

    return {
        small: smallUrl
        , default: defaultUrl
    };
});


/**
 * Job Schema
 */
var JobSchema = new Schema({
    creator: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', index: true, required: true },
});
```

When I try to get the virtual attribute `.profile` from the `job.creator` object, I am missing some values:

```
//controller
Job.populate(job, { path: 'creator', select: '-salt -hashedPassword' }, function(err, job){
    if ( job.creator ) {
        job.creator = job.creator.profile; //this is missing some attributes
    }

    return res.json(job);
})


{
    //...
    creator: {
        favorites: {
            jobs: [ ] //this is not being populated
        }
    }
}
```

Its also missing `job.creator.profileImageUrls` which is a virtual attribute off the User object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not doing the `job.creator = job.creator.profile` line, that doesn't really jibe well with how Mongoose works. Also, where is `profileImageUrls` coming from? Doesn't seem to be in the schema.

Comment: can you look at my posted answer? I got it working, but I don't know what the impact is of doing `job._doc.creator = job.creator.profile`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is desirable, but I got it working with the following:

```
_.each(jobs, function(job, i){
    if ( job.creator ) {
        job._doc.creator = job.creator.profile;
    }
});

res.json(jobs);
```